# filtering text with double quotation marks

Tags: batch-file, filter, text-files

I'm trying to filter the following, but the double quotationmarks are confusing me.

```
(load "")
```

the code I have so far is:

```
find /v ""(load "")" < C:\acadlsip.txt | find /v ""(load "")" > acad.lsp
```

Comment: pls provide an example..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a file (`thing.txt`) with the following content:

```
this is a test.
(load"")
this is more of a test
(load"")
hello.
```

I ran the following command:

```
find /v "(load"""")" < thing.txt
```

and got this output:

```
this is a test.
this is more of a test
hello.
```

Which I guess what you are looking for. The thing to remember here is that entering `""` (two quotes) in the middle of the string is interpreted (in this context) as a single quote.

I will also mention that you don't need to run the same find twice in order to pipe the output to another file. You can instead use this:

```
find /v "(load"""")" < thing.txt > thing2.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
findstr /v (load\"\")  th1.txt > th2.txt
```